# Difference between "después" and "tras"

Tags: uso-de-palabras

"Tras" was in one of the texts we read in Spanish class once and when I looked it up on spanishdict, it said it means "after".

However, when I asked two of the Spanish teachers at my school and my friend who is a native speaker if I could use "tras" interchangeably with "después", they all told me that the two were not the same.

They all told me something about how "tras" is for things directly after another, but I did not really understand it.

Could anyone provide a rule for using the two?

Comment: It would be useful to provide some examples, otherwise the question is a bit broad.

Answer (score 6):

They are similar but not the same.

First of all, `tras` is a preposition, whereas `después` is an adverb. Also, "tras" is used in more formal contexts, so it is unlikely to hear it in a casual conversation.

That being said, there is a clear equivalence between **"tras"** and **"después de"**. Whenever you have a sentence with one of the forms, the other one is equally correct. Again, with the touch of formality when using "tras".

> **[tras](http://dle.rae.es/?id=aOnVELH%7CaOozPBt)**
>
> 1. prep. Después de, a continuación de, aplicado al espacio o al tiempo. *Tras este tiempo vendrá otro mejor*. En voces compuestas, u. c.
>      pref.; p. ej., *trastienda, trascoro*.
> 2. prep. En busca o seguimiento de. *Se fue deslumbrado tras los honores.*
> 3. prep. Detrás de, en situación posterior. *Tras una puerta.*
> 4. prep. Fuera de esto, además. *Tras de venir tarde, regaña.*
>
> **[después](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DQBHjWr)**
>
> 1. adv. Detrás o a continuación. *El ejemplo va después DE la definición.*
> 2. adv. Más tarde, o con posterioridad. *Te veré después. Después DE amanecer. Después DE que llegue.*
> 3. adv. Denota posterioridad en el orden, jerarquía o preferencia. *Esquines fue el mejor orador de Grecia después DE Demóstenes.*

Comment: Es curioso que la RAE no recoja otro significado algo común de *tras* para decir *a través de*.  Lo recoge para la forma *tras-*, pero no para la forma preposicional.  No obstante, creo que una frase como «Tras todo el año, él ha hecho X», la gente la entenderá como «Durante/por todo el año» y no «A la conclusión del año».  En este caso, no creo que sea tan intercambiable con después.